# Getting Monogame content pipeline to work with Visual studio 2013 in windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, monogame, content-pipeline

I've got monogame working in VS 2013 but I can't get the content pipeline to work. When I try to import an existing Content pipeline Project I get the following error.

[image: Cant load content pipeline]

And I can't create a new project since the templates arent installed in 2013.

Since I am running windows 8 I cannot install XNA (installer stops saying it requires Win 7 or Vista). Reading here: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/MonoGame-Content-Processing
It seems XNA is required..?

**EDIT**

Fex answer gets the templates installed in VS 2013 and I can create  a new MonoGame windows Project. But I still cant create or open content projects as they crash with this error

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly XNA is the Windows Phone SDK. Have you tried installing Version 8 instead of 7.11 and see if it works? Would be weird if it wouldnt run on win 8 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Comment: I am running MonoGame on Win8 with VS2012. To use the content pipeline  I had to install VS2010 as well. You should be able to use the VS2010 express version, it is a free download.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad I have installed VS2010 express. How did you get 2012 to load the content pipeline?

Comment: I didn't run it in 2012, I run it in 2010 as a separate project. :-(

Comment: Ah, ok. Then just copying the compiled files over when your done?
Was hoping to avoid two separate solutions.

Comment: I have the same problem and it happens to me on Visual Studio 2010 too. One thing that hits me is that this path clearly is a temp folder and in fact it's empty... maybe it's just an issue with the template path itself? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download this zip - it contains script by Eric Mattison and some other things.
   [Zip - sendspace link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/nmaayz)
2. Extract EricMattisonScript, read and do what Instructions file says.
3. Extract MonoGame.zip to: My documents folder/Visual studio 2013/Templates/Project templates/Visual C#/
4. Extract XNA Game.zip Studio to location $Location where your visual studio 2013 is installed$ ( in my case D:/Program files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 2013)/Common7/IDE/Extensions
5. Launch "devenv.exe /Setup" in command line with administrator priviliages (it is in IDE directory)

Not sure will it work on your pc - in my case it worked.

EDIT: 
[edited script](http://www.sendspace.com/file/l8rudt) - try this edited script, be sure you have XNAGS40_setup in same folder and that you run it with administrator priviliages

Comment: It added Monogame to Vs2013 as a selectable template, and I can create the core monogame Projects from vs 2013 now. But I can not open content pipelines or create new conten projects

Comment: Do you have XNA project template? Did you launch devenv /setup?

Comment: I have XNA in the list of Project templates, and I did launch  devenv /setup. There was no message after launching the  devenv /setup command though so I can only assume it worked.

Comment: Can you load XNA project content template?

Comment: I cant create the XNA content pipeline either as it says these are unsupported too. "Content1.contentproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.contentproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project."

Comment: I'm guessing you replaced all occurances of 11 with 12? I tried that too but dident seem to help. Ran the new script, same problem.

Comment: FYI. Don't do this I can no longer compile monogame. Getting all kinds of weird errors that I did not get before.

Comment: Going through the batch file and undoing all the steps it did solved most of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can install XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh on Windows 8 and 8.1. The issue is that the GFWL it tries to install won't work. So obtain a usable Distributable package, such as from a GFWL game (I believe MS also offers a standalone package), install that, THEN install XNAGS4 Refresh.

CORRECTION: I failed to mention that this does not actually install the necessary project/solution/filetypes into VS2012. See the next section for useful solutions.
ADDITIONAL INFO: At the renamed XNA CodePlex page (http://mxa.codeplex.com), there are downloads for versions of Visual Studio beyond 2010 (10.0). These downloads are ZIP files that include installers for each separate package that XNA4 installs, ending with the VS extension package installer for the relevant version of Visual Studio.
In addition, MonoGame at this point (two years later) no longer requires any XNA elements to load and compile in Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop. The tools that MonoGame uses to replace XNA Content Projects can also import them for conversion to MonoGame Content Projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the content pipeline of SharpDX.
You put your content in the Content folder of the SharpDX solution. Build that solution and then you move the .xnb files generated to the content folder of your MonoGame project.

You could also just use a post buid event to copy the files for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right the Content Pipeline project is at the core a Windows Phone 7 XNA project. Since VS2013 it became unable to create or edit Windows Phone 7 nor XNA projects and thereby unable for you to open the Content Pipeline project.

For so as far as I know to create/compile the Pipeline you'll need VS2012 or VS2010.

VS2010 has XNA bundled within and for VS2012 to work you would need to download the Windows Phone SDK to enable XNA development. (this is also what I use for my Pipeline)